# Sphinx Search - No results returned on Numeric and Alpha-Numeric search

Tags: php, sphinx, keyword, numeric, alphanumeric

I'am trying to use sphinx search to provide keyword search feature to a web application i'am working on.

I have tried everything to get the numeric and alpha-numeric search to work, but found no luck! (tried to configure sphinx.conf using charset_table, index_exact_words, infix, substring).

Here is the sphinx.conf file settings:

```
source src1 : base_src
{
    sql_query          = SELECT CRC32(string_field1) AS id, 1 AS table_id, \
       string_field1, string_field2, string_field3, string_field4, string_field5 \
       FROM table1
    sql_query_info     = SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CRC32(string_field1)=$id
    sql_attr_uint      = table_id
    sql_attr_string    = string_field1
}

index idx1
{
    morphology          = stem_en
    max_substring_len   = 0
    min_infix_len       = 1
    enable_star         = 1
    expand_keywords     = 1
    dict                = keywords
    mlock               = 0
    min_word_len        = 1
    charset_type        = utf-8
    charset_table       = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
    index_exact_words   = 1
    source              = src1
    path                = /home/{myUserName}/indices/idx1
}
```

here **string_field1** is an alpha-numeric string.

**Example:**

**string_field1** = "HMGC_GL0000047"

$sphinx->query('GL0', 'idx1');

or

$sphinx->query('047', 'idx1');

how to configure and use sphinx + php to make the numeric and alpha-numeric search work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined **string_field1** as an attribute, with `sql_attr_string`.

Because its an `Attribute`, it's NOT full-text indexed. So it will never match any keywords in the search.

`Fields` on the other hand ARE indexed, and would match. Anything not defined as an attribute, and never the first column in `sql_query`, but everything else will be a field.

So can either remove sql_attr_string if you diddnt really want it to work as an attribute. Or can use sql_field_string, to make the column BOTH a field and attribute. Once you string_field1 defined as a feild, it should match on your query.

Comment: **@barryhunter** >> adding sql_field_string has done the job, but the indexing and querying is taking 4x more time. is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Probably not a lot to do be done about indexing. It just doing more work now, so will be slower. But for searching there is hope, see http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1784 (although you could just switch to dict=crc in the meantime)

Comment: isn't the default option for dict is crc?

Comment: But you have dict=keywords in your index, so have choosen it already! But the default has recently changed, so depends on sphinx version.

Comment: Hoping they would come up with Hybrid indexing!, thank you **@barryhunter** for your valuable information. :)